# Apache 403 215 (on windows)

Tags: windows, http, apache2, fastcgi

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
<Directory "C:\Apache24">
    SetHandler fcgi-script
    Order Allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
ScriptAlias /host1/ "C:\http\fast_cgi.exe"
```

In log file access:

> ::1 - - [30/Aug/2016:17:06:49 -0300] "GET /host1/ HTTP/1.1" 403 215

Comment: is `c:\apache24` your site's document root, or is the doc root at least somewhere below that directory?

Comment: Yes, http://imgur.com/u9lPjG1

Comment: Added Output and Tag